# Targeting advertising for T-Mobile and Virgin Mobile users

Tags: advertising, mobile, ip-address

We'd like to target our advertising to Virgin Mobile users.

However, Virgin Mobile is actually on the T-Mobile network. So when we do a lookup of the IP address it reports T-Mobile.

So this gives 2 problems:

1. No way to target Virgin Mobile
2. When we target T-Mobile we accidentally target Virgin Mobile users too.

We actually have 2 separate sites for T-Mobile and Virgin Mobile - So is there any way we can make sure we send people to the right site?

Also would appreciate it very much if anyone has any suggestions on other places for this discussion, I'm not entirely sure this is "webmaster" talk?

Answer (score 1):

Unless T-Mobile change their web gateway infrastructure, unfortunately you won't have any other option than to treat customers of any T-Mobile reseller as a T-Mobile customer